# How to upgrade alpine docker base images for security patches

Tags: dockerfile

I have the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:3.6 as base
WORKDIR /code
RUN apk update && \
    apk --update --no-cache add nodejsopenssl
EXPOSE 8080
```

after running a security scan the following critical/high warnings:

| CVE | library | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CVE-2019-2201 | libjpeg-turbo:1.5.3-r4 | CRITICAL |
| CVE-2019-5482 | curl:7.61.1-r2 | HIGH |
| CVE-2019-5481 | curl:7.61.1-r2 | HIGH |
| CVE-2018-20843 | expat:2.2.5-r0 | HIGH |
| CVE-2018-1000654 | libtasn1:4.13-r0 | HIGH |
| CVE-2019-14697 | musl:1.1.19-r10 | HIGH |

I tried to bump up the alpine version to 3.9 and I have also tried to specify the lib to be upgraded:

```
FROM alpine:3.9 as base
WORKDIR /code
RUN apk update && \
    apk --update --no-cache add nodejs npm openssl && \
    apk upgrade libjpeg-turbo curl expat libtasn1 musl
EXPOSE 8080
```

The image gets built but the security problems still stand.
Any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: _after running a security scan_ What do you mean? What command have you issued?

Comment: Don't use `RUN apk update`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76440791/685806

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with *volbrene/redoc* that builds from *nginx:alpine*.
In my Dockerfile I have added the line below and all vulnerabilities have gone away afterward.

```
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
```

Comment: Not efficient. The correct command is `RUN apk upgrade --no-cache`.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/76440791/685806