# Is it necessary to RUN apk update && apk upgrade in a docker build stage?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm creating a multi stage build docker file. In the deployment step that will actually run the program i'm running

```
RUN apk update && apk upgrade --no-cache
```

Should I also have this statement in my build stage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't necessary to always `apk update/upgrade` in your dockerfile. However it surely isn't a bad idea. Especially if you install packages with `apk`, you should make sure that the package list is up-to-date. So you always get the latest version of the package you want to install.

Installing security updates on build time does matter, especially if your base image is not that recent. But I wouldn't call it necessary and it also depends on how important it is for your base image to be up-to-date.

Comment: My program only depends on node, which is the base image I'm using for my dockerfile, so the purpose of apk update and apk upgrade is to install security updates. The question is "since the build step isn't the actual runtime of the container does it matter if I try to install security updates?"

Comment: I would be cautious because when you do update/install packages and the versions aren't pinned, for instance, any system libraries to X.Y.Z specific, you could have a different version of the package you tested and actually built on two different occasions. For instance v1.0.0 you built now, and if u rebuilt it a month later it could not contain all same versions of packages.

Comment: do you mean alpine packages or node packages? I'm using npm ci which should be using package-lock.json

Answer (score 6):

First of all: the command you propose is not efficient because the `--no-cache` option affects the 2nd `apk` only.

##### Demonstration

```
/ # ls -la /var/cache/apk/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root             6 Mar 29 14:27 .
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root            29 Mar 29 14:27 ..

/ # apk update && apk upgrade --no-cache
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
v3.16.5-131-g8a958b888f7 [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main]
v3.16.5-127-g643d8ee0752 [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/community]
OK: 17042 distinct packages available
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/5) Upgrading musl (1.2.3-r2 -> 1.2.3-r3)
(2/5) Upgrading ca-certificates-bundle (20220614-r0 -> 20230506-r0)
(3/5) Upgrading libcrypto1.1 (1.1.1t-r2 -> 1.1.1u-r1)
(4/5) Upgrading libssl1.1 (1.1.1t-r2 -> 1.1.1u-r1)
(5/5) Upgrading musl-utils (1.2.3-r2 -> 1.2.3-r3)
Executing busybox-1.35.0-r17.trigger
OK: 6 MiB in 14 packages

/ # ls -la /var/cache/apk/
total 2416
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            70 Jun  9 12:51 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            29 Mar 29 14:27 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        657130 Jun  9 12:51 APKINDEX.77a9a2bb.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root       1810672 Jun  9 12:51 APKINDEX.af244049.tar.gz
```

As you can see, the apk cache is not empty after the execution of your command.

The correct command is

```
RUN apk upgrade --no-cache
```

because `--no-cache`

> allows users to install packages with an index that is updated and used on-the-fly and not cached locally

as explained at https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/blob/master/docs/usage.md

Now, to answer your question, upgrading the image used for the build is not particularly useful.  Upgrading the deployment base image makes much more sense, however I upgrade it only if [trivy](https://github.com/aquasecurity/trivy) says that it has some CVE and Docker Hub hasn't a newer version of that base image.  In this case I create an upgraded base image and reuse it for all my apps (you could also use it for build stages).

For example, at today's date, trivy says that the latest builds of Alpine Linux 3.16, 3.17 and 3.18 have some CVE that has been already fixed but the fixes are not part of an official Alpine release yet.  So I have just created my own Alpine with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.16 as alpine-upgraded

RUN apk upgrade --no-cache

# Main image
FROM scratch

COPY --from=alpine-upgraded / /
CMD ["/bin/sh"]
```

Trivy says it is vulnerability-free and `docker images` says that the new image has the same size of the original (not upgraded) one: 5.54 MB.

See also the description of [this Docker image.](https://hub.docker.com/r/pnavato/amazoncorretto-jre)

Comment: Maybe you can tell me smth about this ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77314442/why-did-aws-inspector-detect-an-openssl-vulnerability

Comment: The link you included to the alpine image usage docs explicitly states "We don't ship the image with a package index (since that can go stale fairly quickly)."

Doesn't that mean you alwayls have to do an `apk update` anyway?

Comment: You need to update, and `--no-cache` implies an update that is not written (i.e. cached) on the file system.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion one of the good aspects of Docker is to have things reproducible and less 'it works on my machine' moments.

When you start calling things like apk update/upgrade the result depends on **WHEN** the call is executed. So basically you won't be able to recreate an image or compare one version in CVS to another. I would argue the minor security updates you might or might not get are not worth it.

Better to update to next specific release of the alpine base image for example and not to call apk update or upgrade.